# Is there any option to change font and size in kibana 8.7.1 version?

Tags: kibana

There is a requirement to customize Kibana branding. I need help changing the font size, font color, and logo. I also want to define series colors according to my requirements and set them as default. Additionally, I need to change the loader icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screenshots from [@xeraa recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76501245/10685211). Thanks!

The screenshots from elastic cloud ES v8.8
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for providing the details. Can you please guide me how Can I change the font and size of the font in Kibana 8.7.1 or 8.8

Comment: You're welcome. There is no easy way to change the font size. But you can change the font size of the browser!

Answer (score 1):

[8.8.0 brought some of these changes](https://www.elastic.co/blog/whats-new-kibana-ml-8-8-0):

> The logo, organization name, page title, and browser icon can be customized globally via the new “Global Settings” tab in the Advanced Settings section of Stack Management. Making these changes requires Kibana admin access and an enterprise license, and the changes apply to all spaces.